# Is there any TTPickerTextField alternative? perhaps in iOS4?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, three20

Is there an alternative or new stuff in iOS4 that resembles `TTPickerTextField`

I am looking for a way to recreate the "new mail" control view and I've read about `TTPickerTextField`. Three20 is my last option (especially as it has no iPad version) and I wanted to know if iOS4 gives some new UI controls to do this.

Comment: Did you found any solution? Please help .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a dump (with some details clipped out) of the view hierarchy of a mail composer on iPhone.

```
<UILayoutContainerView>
   | <UINavigationTransitionView>
   |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView>
   |    |    | <MFMailComposeView>
   |    |    |    | <UIView>
   |    |    |    |    | <MFComposeScrollView>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_MFComposeRecipientView>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MFRecipientTextField>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MFHeaderLabelView>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MFComposeMultiView>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MFHeaderLabelView>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MFComposeSubjectView>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MFHeaderLabelView>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITextField>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITextFieldLabel>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <MFComposeTextContentView>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MFComposeBodyField>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView>
   | <UINavigationBar>
   |    | <UINavigationItemView>
   |    | <UINavigationButton>
   |    |    | <UIImageView>
   |    |    | <UIButtonLabel>
   |    | <UINavigationButton>
   |    |    | <UIImageView>
   |    |    | <UIButtonLabel>
```

You will find that all of the `MFCompose___View`s are not documented. This means they are off limits. As far as I've seen, there is no such control available in iOS 4.

I don't recommend Three20 just to use one element. It substantially increases compile time, and I've found several bugs with Three20. It's good, but could be much better.

I would highly recommend checking out [Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/), if you haven't already. You might find what you want there. [Github](https://github.com/) is also another great source.

If you do end up using `TTPickerTextField` and find that it's buggy, you can always rewrite the code from scratch or fix the bug in the source code.

**EDIT:**

I found a control via Cocoa Controls that should do what you want. You can find it on Github. It's called [TITokenFieldView](https://github.com/thermogl/TITokenFieldView).

Here's another one on Github called [JSTokenField](https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField).

I've never used either token field, so I can't vouch for their quality.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check cocoacontrols.com